# How to bind a list of objects of a class to a datagridview whose one field is again an object of some other class?

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datagridview

I have following code in which i have to bind a list of objects of a class to a datagridview. In this class one field is an object of some other class which again have some fields in it.Please refer the code.

```
public class Test
{
    public string m_field1_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field2_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field3_Test { get; set; }
    public string m_field4_Test { get; set; }
    .
    .
    public string m_field100_Test{get; set;}
    public Test1 test1obj;

    public Test()
    {
        m_field1_Test = "field1";
        m_field2_Test = "field2";
        m_field3_Test = "field3";
        m_field4_Test = "field4";
        .
        .
        m_field100_Test = "field100";

        test1obj = new Test1();
    }
}

public class Test1
{
    public string m_field1_Test1;
    public string m_field2_Test1;
    public string m_field3_Test1; 
    .
    .
    .
    public string m_field30_Test1;   

    public Test1()
    {

        m_field1_Test1 = "field1_Test1";
        m_field2_Test1 = "field2_Test1";
        m_field3_Test1 = "field3_Test1"; 
        .
        .
        .
        m_field30_Test1 = "field30_Test1";
    }       
}
```

On a Button click i am binding a list of Test Objects to dataGridView. Code is as follows.

```
   private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Test> listTest = new List<Test>();
        Test obj;
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            obj = new Test();
            listTest.Add(obj);
        }
        label1.Text = listTest.Count().ToString();
        dataGridView1.DataSource = listTest;
        dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = Color.Beige;                
    }
```

When i execute this much part only field1 to field4 are appearing in the datagridview. How can i bind it in such a way so that Test1 fields also appear in datagridview in format.I want output something like this.

```
     field1 | field2  | field3| ....field100|field1_Test1 |field2_Test1|...field30_Test1
            |         |       |             |              |            |
            |         |       |             |              |            |
            |         |       |             |              |            |
```

Can someone please tell me how to implement this functionality??

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are doing, but it looks like you want `Test` to *inherit* from `test1` rather than just instantiating it. You want `test` to have `test1` properties?

Comment: Please try to examine this tuturial on DataBinding, it has the information you need http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24656/A-Detailed-Data-Binding-Tutorial

Comment: @paqogomez no i dont wnat Test to inherit from Test1. I want to bind fields of Test1 to datagridview using object of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transforming your `listTest` to an anonymous object before you bind will expose the fields.

```
var dataSource = listTest.Select(l => new {field1 = l.m_field1_Test, 
                                           field2 = l.m_field2_Test, 
                                           field3 = l.m_field3_Test, 
                                           field4 = l.m_field4_Test,
                                           field1_Test1 = l.test1obj.m_field1_Test1,
                                           field2_Test1 = l.test1obj.m_field2_Test1, 
                                           field3_Test1 = l.test1obj.m_field3_Test1});
```

This would be better accomplished in your loop to 1000000, but I figured that looping to 1000000 is not something you would do in production.

If you wanted to eliminate the for loop, you could do the same with `Enumerable.Range`:

```
var dataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000000).Select(...
```

Also, just a tip, you should avoid putting logic into your event handlers.  Pull it into its own method so it can be reused in other places.

Comment: can you share the complete logic as this is not working at my end.

Comment: @Neha I've created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lEh20o) to show how its transformed.

Comment: for console you have iterated datasource using "item". In my code i am assigning datagridview1.datasource with datasource created using LINQ.But again it doesnt work.data is coming into datasource but it is not getting bind with the gridview control.

Comment: finally it worked a small thing was there i missed.Thanks a ton @paqogomez

Comment: @Neha Excellent! I was worried I had missed something. Thanks for the answer (and upvote ;) !

Comment: but i figured out this is not an efficient method as the memory consumption in case of large object will be significant.Can we find other way round for this problem. m sure there will be some more efficient approach.

Comment: it is not efficient, that is true.  The answer depends on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: the class is actually having around 100 public fields and the object of other class have 30 fields. so in this way i have to write 130 assignment statement in linq......do we have some other way to do so....so that i can create a new list without explicitly assigning items???

Comment: @Neha you can use reflection to loop through your properties(they should be made as properties not fields).  You can also use expressions to dynamically create queries.  Thats a lot of dynamic however.  You might want to think of a better architecture.